# GridView in panel not loading while panel is hidden

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a page with 2 panels. Active panel is set by a dropdown. Panel A is set to visible="true", panel B is set to visible="false" by default.

Within each panel is a GridView. The visible panel grid will have data populated in it when the page loads, but the grid on panel B will display an empty set. If I hit the search button on that panel (for that specific grid), it will then populate data.

If I switch it around and make panel B visible & A hidden, grid B will have data and grid A won't. Search will then load it. If I set both panels to be visible, both grids will populate.

This is in my page load function:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        table_dropdown.SelectedIndex = 0 'setting the default to view Table A

        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE A"
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE B"
End If
```

And my various panel & grid declarations:

```
<asp:Panel ID="TPAnnuity_Panel" runat="server" visible="true">
    <asp:GridView ID="TPAnnuity_GridView" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" Runat="server"
            DataSourceID="TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="AnnuityTotalPointsID" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" PageSize="20">
    </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="TPLife_Panel" runat="server" visible="false">
    <asp:GridView ID="TPLife_GridView" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" Runat="server"
            DataSourceID="TPLife_SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="LifeTotalPointsID" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" PageSize="20">
    </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
```

What gives? Did I miss something blatant? I use setups like this on multiple other pages, and have compared. Can't see the issue.

Comment: it will not render the data if the parent container set to visible false.
Use a css class for hiding the panel

Comment: @Legends In other applications, I use a DataBind() instead of this DataSource.SelectCommand, and those render fine. Is it a case of different functions doing different stuff?

Comment: Actually there would be no Gridview at all, when setting the gv to visible false, so in ur case it has to be related with the databind, that would be my guess too. I dont work with this datasource crap...
But why does the GridA contain data, hm very strange

Comment: can u debugg the databinding event of the sqldatasource, if its getting hit?!

Answer (score 0):

The other examples that worked had the select command baked right into the .aspx file, like so:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource" Runat="server"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Table A"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Table A () Values () "
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Table A Set Stuff = This">
```

I originally only had the Insert and Updates here, and had the data bind in the back end.